# Troubles with getting name of the default browser in Android

Tags: android, browser, default

In my app i need to get name of the browser that is set as default in Android. When user has set some browser as default, everything is cool and i can get its name. But when there is no default browser, i am always getting the string **"com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity"** as name of the default browser. How can i check that there is no default browsers in Android? Thanks. This is my code:

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://"));
    ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(browserIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
    Log.d("Log", "PCG NAME: " + packageName);
```

Comment: You have answer in your question that your getting **com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity** so that you would know that there is no default browser.

Comment: yeah, but com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity is not a browser name. And i am wondering why this is happening. If there is no default browser on device why not to get a null-pointer exception. Of course i can make a check, and when i will get this name, i will know that there is no default browser. But there is a big risk that on other devices i will get some other string.